# Namba forcing, one Cardinal up

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The classical Namba forcing collapses $\omega_2$ to have cofinality $\omega$ while preserving the cardinal $\omega_1$. Higher analogs were constructed to (under some additional hypotheses) give a cardinal $\omega_n$ cofinality $\omega$ while preserving $\omega_k$ for $k<n$.

However, i am interested in a different generalisation which collapses to $\omega_1$ instead of $\omega$. So: Does there (consistently) exist a forcing notion that forces $\omega_3$ to have cofinality $\omega_1$ while preserving $\omega_2$?

Comment: Since this will violate covering, it will require a stronger hypothesis than just ZFC.

Comment: It is possible with the help of a Woodin cardinal and a stationary tower forcing $\mathbb{P}_\delta$. (You may find a proof from Larson's book about the stationary tower.)

Comment: You are right, it is example 2.4.4. If you add your comment as an answer, id happily accept it.

Comment: I may add an answer to your question, but I think [an answer for a relevant question is available on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661008/53976), which is better.